# Uploading Problems with laravel and php on centos7

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel, vps

I have purchase web application online for cloud storage and file sharing. And i was uplaoded it on my vps server. server configuration is 2core processor and 4GB ram. My web application is written in php and laravel. 
I was hosted this web app on my vps server. And try to upload file. First file i have uploaded and file size was 25MB.It was successfully uploaded. But i have try to upload file up to 312 MB but it can not upload.It some times upload and some times fails. Why this happen ? I have change some parameters in php.ini

```
max_file_size = 1024MB
post_file_size = 1024MB
memory = 512MB
max_execution_time = 500000
max_input_time = 50000
```

I have monitor server monitor not used more memory. Buf file is some times upload or some time it can not be uploaded. It's happen if i upload file more than 100MB.

Any one tell me why this happen? It's happen because my internet? 
But if i upload 500MB to google drive with my internet it was successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you change the correct php.ini file according to your active php version and php-fpm/php-cli selected?

Comment: I am sure i have change this parameters in /etc/php.ini.

Comment: Hi @AdventureSearcher welcome to SO, please use the comments section to ask for clarifications on questions, also have a look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :)

Comment: Hi, I am sure for the changes. i have changed max_uploading_file and post_uploading. if i change memory = -1 then it's unlimited ? And what can i do for unmeter max_execution time and max_post_time ?

Comment: @sammy-j I cannot use the comments sections because my reputation is less then 50

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you typically need to change in your `php.ini` to increase maximum size of uploaded file are:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

and

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 1024M
```

Additionally check the value of `memory_limit` as it may also affect maximum possible size of uploaded files:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

Remember to restart your HTTP server after saving the changes for the new configuration to take effect.

Parameter names you posted in your question seem to be not correct. Were they present in your `php.ini` with different values assigned or did you just add them to the file ?